# git lg|more command print `ESC[33m|` on MacOS

Tags: git, macos

`git lg` works but `git lg|more` doesn't.

my `git lg` command is:

```
alias.lg=log --color --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

It works well on linux, but on MacOS(iTerm) the output is quite strange：
[on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBsUU.png)   
 [onMacOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO3c2.png)

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Comment: What have you set your pager to (core.pager, $GIT_PAGER, etc)? Are you using Terminal, iTerm2, or some other terminal emulator?

Comment: @torek  core.parger=cat, and I use iTerm2.

Comment: iTerm2 should be fine, and `cat` wouldn't do that. Something (e.g., `less` perhaps) is running *without* `-FR` or equivalent options. If you've set `core.parger` rather than `core.pager` you'll be getting some built in pager, but normally if Git is using `less`, Git has also set `$LESS` to `FRX`.